# Straightforward way to store protobuf java object in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, protocol-buffers, mongodb-java, proto, protobuf-java

When there is a need to store protobuf3 message coming in form of Java instance (from the generated java class), the best option is to store the object itself and later to read it back from the database.

My usecase it to store such messages in Mongodb.
While investigating this, I couldn't find a way, so decided to ask here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could transform the Protobufs Java class to JSON and from JSON to an `org.bson.Document` and then write the document and reverse that transform when reading.

See [JsonFormat](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/) for more details.

Here's a simple example on the write side:

```
YourProtobufsClass anInstance = YourProtobufsClass.getDefaultInstance();

String json = JsonFormat.printer().print(yourProtobufsClass); 

Document document = Document.parse(json);

mongoClient.getDatabase(...).getCollection(...).insertOne(document);
```

Here's a simple example on the read side:

```
JsonFormat.Parser parser = JsonFormat.parser();

FindIterable<Document> documents = collection.find(...);
for (Document document : documents) {
  YourProtobufsClass.Builder builder = YourProtobufsClass.newBuilder();

  parser.merge(document.toJson(), builder);

  // now you can build an instance of your protobufs class which 
  // has been populated from the retrieved JSON
  YourProtobufsClass anInstance = builder.build();
}
```

Comment: Used above way to store Protobufs java classes into mongo db. It throws `No field is annotated with @Id; but it is required` and `org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Number of violations: 1` errors

Comment: That error is related to using [morphia](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia) as an intermediary between the Java code layer and MongoDB. The original question (and answer) did not involve [morphia](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia) at all.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: Hi @glytching. Just wondering if converting to JSON and then to BSON will affect the performance? Is there a way to write my own proto-BSON parser? Found this issue: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/2601.

Comment: @james.bondu converting to BSON via JSON will certainly add to the execution time. Whether that additional time will "affect the performance" is probably something only you can know since you can determine whether **your** system can afford that extra time.

Comment: Is performance a concern with this approach? Compared to protobuf->BSON generators like for Go https://github.com/gogo/protobuf. Also, your approach has the benefit of not having to do manual tagging.

Comment: Hi @glytching, the above solution is taking lot of time if the size of proto message is around 10 mb , any suggestion for this case ?

Comment: @james.bondu and @ onepiece, can you please suggest if any way to do proto <=> bson